# Sizing bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

i have image with custom size and i want to show it on my website with carousel bootstrap but i am stuck to styling the carousel

> this is the result
> [image]

> i want align the picture to center

This is my code
i just add style width on my html code

```
<div class="carousel-inner" style="width: 50%;">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="img\post1.jpg"" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h5>First slide label</h5>
                            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I would remove the width:50% (leave it to expand) and try centring the image element only? I believe the Carousel already centres the content by default:
.carousel-item img { margin: auto }

Comment: @Teknotica i have try that but the transition is look bad, the image become landscape and stretch :(

Comment: remove `width: 50%` and set `object-fit: cover` for img. maybe fixed!

Comment: This is just guesswork at the moment but try `<img src="img\post1.jpg"" class="d-flex align-items-center" alt="...">`

Comment: Or put the image exactly where it is but inside a div of it's own and try `<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">`

Comment: @kian its work but the transition become landscape and stretch

Comment: Remove `d-block w-100` from your code but leave the `d-flex......` info from above (whichever of the two above worked for you).

Comment: @Ihda Anwari Great, glad it's solved. Vote me up if you're having a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `d-flex` on the image like this....

```
<img src="img\post1.jpg" class="d-flex align-items-center" alt="...">
```

or add a Div around the image and use `d-flex` like this....

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <img src="img\post1.jpg" alt="...">
</div>
```

Then from your code remove

```
d-block w-100
```

As a side note, you have 2 sets of quote marks at the end of your image path....

```
 <img src="img\post1.jpg""
```